# How to manage parallel HTTP request that are based on Message Queuing Listneners (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, http, asynchronous, microservices, mqtt

I'm sure this kind of problem have been resolved here many time but I can't find how those question was formulated.

I have a micro-services that handle the communication between my infrastructure and a MQTT Broker. Every time a HTTP request is received I send a "Who is alive in the room XXX ?" message on the MQTT Broker, and every client registered on the "XXX/alive" topic have to answer and I wait Y milliseconds before closing the request by sending back the responses received to the client.

It works well when I'm handling one request. But it screws up when more than one request is asked at a time.

Here is the Express route handling the HTTP requests :

```
app.get('/espPassports', (req, res) => {
  mqttHelper.getESPPassports(req.query.model_Name).then((passports) => {
    res.send(passports).end();
  }).catch(err => {
    res.send(err).end();
  })
})
```

Here is how the getESPPassports works :

```
getESPPassports: async (model_Name) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Say there is a request performed
      ongoing_request.isOpen = true;
      ongoing_request.model_Name = model_Name;
      //  Ask who is alive
      con.publish(topic, "ASK");
      setTimeout(() => {
      // If no answer after given timeout
        if (ongoing_request.passports.length == 0) {
          reject({ error: "No MQTT passports found" });
      // Else send a deep clone of the answers (else it's empty)
        } else {
          resolve(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ongoing_request.passports)));
        }
      // Delete the current request object and 'close it'
        ongoing_request.passports.length = 0;
        ongoing_request.isOpen = false;
        ongoing_request.model_Name = ""
      }, process.env.mqtt_timeout || 2000)
    })
  }
};
```

And here is the MQTT listener :

```
con.on("message", (topic, message) => {
      // If a passport is received check the topic and if there is a request opened
      if (_checkTopic(topic) && ongoing_request.isOpen) {
        try {
          ongoing_request.passports.push(JSON.parse(message));
        } catch (error) {
      // do stuff if error
        }
      }
  }
})
```

I know the problem come from the boolean i'm using to specify if there is a request ongoing, I was thinking to create an object for each new request and identify them by a unique id (like a timetamp) but I have no way to make the MQTT listneners to know this unique id.

I have some other solution in mind but I'm not sure they'll work and I feel like there is a way to handle that nicely that I don't know about.

Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate a unique id for each request and include it in the MQTT message, you can then cache the Express response object keyed by the unique id.

The devices need to include the unique id in their responses so they can be paired up with the right response.

The other approach is just to cache responses from the devices and assign the cache a Time to Live so you don't need to ask the devices every time.